# a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Now I have a String and I want to delete \n and convert \u to \\u.

If the String contains \\u,I will not change it to \\\u.

I want to use String.replaceAll(), but I don`t know how to write the regular expression.

please help me. thanks.

example:

\u => \\u

\\u => \\u  (do nothing)

Comment: When you say change `\u` to `\\u` you mean that given `"\\u"` you want `"\\\\u"`? (A few examples would be useful! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using a negative look-behind. (Changes `\u` to `\\u` only if it is *not* preceeded by a `\`.)

```
String in = "lorem ipsum \\u dolor \\\\u sit \n amet";

System.out.println(in);
System.out.println(in.replaceAll("\\n", "")
                     .replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\u", "\\\\\\\\u"));
```

**Prints:**

```
lorem ipsum \u dolor \\u sit 
 amet
lorem ipsum \\u dolor \\u sit  amet
```

- `\n` removed
- The first `\u` is changed to `\\u` but while `\\u` is preserved as it is.

Comment: Could you explain the need for so much escaping? Shouldn't \\ be enough to escape \ (I am not particularly conversant with Java)

Comment: A backslash in a Java string literal needs to be escaped, so `"\\"` represents the string \. Regular expression treats \ specially too, so there you have another level of escaping.